# How to make splashscreenimage to work in ios phonegap apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, splash-screen

i'm developing phonegap app 2.9.0 in visual studio 2012 on windows 8. When i run my app in windows emulator everything works fine. I used adobe.phonegap.build to build my app for ios.
And build worked properly and installed that .ipa file in my iphone everything works fine other than splashscreenimage. Instead of that a white background is appearing in my iphone. Is there any way to make my splashscreen to work?

Somebody please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified in a **config.xml**, iOS platform will try to use the default `icon.png` during compilation. To define specific icons please use the guide provided: [Configure Icons and Splash Screens](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html).

The default icon must be named icon.png and must reside in the root of your application folder.

Also,Using a splash screen is rather easy via the PhoneGap Build config.xml file.

Write a bit of JavaScript that made use of the PhoneGap Splash Screen API:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(e) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    },5000);

}, "false");
```

Comment: i already added this script. Its working fine in windows emulator(i.e) while running in visual studio. Its not working in iphone. A white screen is appearing instead of the splashscreen.

Comment: Your answer is correct but i need a solution for developing the app in visual studio. not in xcode.